# Distinguish instances of objects implementing an interface, by an enum value or by its implementing interface

Tags: java, interface, enums, instanceof, modularity

The situation is that i have this interface:

```
interface ISymbol
{

}
```

and these classes:

```
class Letter implements ISymbol
{

}

class Number implements ISymbol
{

}

class LowerCaseLetter extends Letter
{

}

class UpperCaseLetter extends Letter
{

}
```

Now lets say that i have this function, in a different class.
The logic that this class performs DOES NOT belong in the implementation of the ISymbol
classes:

```
class SymbolMonitor
{
void func(ISymbol[] symbols)
{
    for (ISymbol iSymbol : symbols)
    {
        // If the symbol is a number 
        // or a lower case letter do something.
    }
}
}
```

But i don't want to check for those two types specifically because i might have other implementing classes of ISymbol that will also require the same logic.

My question is about the preferred way of action.
I have two solutions to the problem.
1. Create an like so:

```
enum SymbolType
{
    NORMAL,
    SPECIAL1,
    SPECIAL2,
}
```

and add to the code:

```
    interface ISymbol
{
    SymbolType getType();
}

class SymbolMonitor
{
    void func(ISymbol[] symbols)
{
    for (ISymbol iSymbol : symbols)
    {
            if(iSymbol.getType().equals(SymbolType.SPECIAL1))
                    {
                        // Do special1 logic
                    }
            if(iSymbol.getType().equals(SymbolType.SPECIAL2))
                    {
                        // Do special2 logic
                    }
    }
}
}
```

1. I can create empty interfaces and use the instanceof function.

   ```
   interface ISpecialSymbol1
   ```

   {

   }

   interface ISpecialSymbol2
   {

   }

   class LowerCaseLetter extends Letter implements ISpecialSymbol1
   {

   }

   class Number implements ISymbol, ISpecialSymbol1
   {

   }

so that the function will be:

```
class SymbolMonitor
{
void func(ISymbol[] symbols)
{
    for (ISymbol iSymbol : symbols)
    {
        if(iSymbol instanceof ISpecialSymbol1)
        {
            // Do special 1 logic.
        }
        if(iSymbol instanceof ISpecialSymbol2)
        {
            // Do special 2 logic.
        }
    }
}
}
```

I think that the second option is much more simpler, but I am new to java and I am not sure at all what is the correct way of action to use.

Comment: Use polymorphism to your advantage. Try to avoid `instanceof` and type checks.

Comment: You mean move the logic into the class? because i have an external function using the ISymbol, not logic the belongs inside the classes.

Comment: There are a number of patterns to achieve this indirection. `Visitor` might be one of them. Check it out.

Comment: This does not source like an enum to me.  If it's too complex and convoluted, it might not be a good idea.  I'd rethink this.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a method in interface:

```
interface ISymbol
{
   public void doSomething();
}
```

And any implementing classes can override and specify their desired behavior. In this case:

```
class Letter implements ISymbol
{
    public void doSomething() {
         //do Nothing
    }
}

class Number implements ISymbol
{
     public void doSomething() {
         //do Something
    }
}

class LowerCaseLetter extends Letter
{
    public void doSomething() {
         //do Something
    }
}

class UpperCaseLetter extends Letter
{
    public void doSomething() {
         //do Nothing
    }
}
```

And then you can directly call ISymbol.doSomething()

```
void func(ISymbol[] symbols)
{
    for (ISymbol iSymbol : symbols)
    {
        iSymbol.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: The doSomething function has to deal with instances of objects that the ISymbol deriving class should not have access to, unless i want to break the logic layers which will have to be pretty ugly.

Comment: In that case, the `doSomething` method can be renamed to `canDoSomething()` which will return a boolean. All overriding methods can then return a true if they can "doSomething" or else false. In the for loop, you can then have an if condition `if(iSymbol.doSomething())` then doSomething()

Comment: Well that is exactly what i meant with the enum option, just using enums instead of boolean vaues.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a near verbatim quote of the motivation given for the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) in "[Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29)". In code, this would be something like:

```
interface Visitor {
    void visit(Letter letter);
    void visit(Number number);
    // ...
}

interface ISymbol {
    void visit(Visitor v);
}

class Letter {
    @Override void visit(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

class Number {
    @Override void visit(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Using an enum is a viable alternative if the visitors can remain agnostic of which type they operate on (because the visitor only uses methods all Symbols have). If the visitor does need to cast to the respective symbol type, I would prefer the visitor pattern.

I usually prefer the visitor pattern over a series of instanceof checks because the visitor pattern enables the compiler to verify that all visitors handle all symbol types - so if you add a symbol type, all exisiting visitors will no longer compile until you have specified how to handle this new type.

Comment: I understand your answer and i would have accept it, but using the visitor forces me to export most of the logic into god classes so that all the logic will be available to all layers of the code.
Which now makes the question, should i break the layers causing Coupling so that the visitors will have access to logic of upper layers, or use an enum. and if i am using an enum, why is it better then the instanceof way?

Comment: What do you mean with "god class"? And I don't see how the visitor pattern would require you to break layers (The visitor implementations need not be public, nor reside in the same layer as the visitor interface ...)

Comment: I have a function in a layer above the one where the ISymbol inherited classes reside.
This function has a different function for ISymbol types.
To implement the Visitor pattern here i will have to let the ISymbol have access to the functionality of the above layer.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "have access". ISymbol will only refer to IVisitor, which is in the same layer. It does not know the classes implementing IVisitor, nor even require there are any in the classpath. Those classes are therefore not dependencies of ISymbol, and the rule that each layer only depends on layers below it is satisfied.

Comment: You are right, but the implementing classes of IVisitor (which also implements ISymbol) will have to be able to invoke functions or carry out logic of a layer above them.

Comment: And why can't they be in that layer themselves?

Comment: Lets say i have the class Book.
Now the class book has alot of symbols.
He has a state machine that needs to know the current symbol read for display, so by the type of symbol he knows how to display the data that is published by the symbols.